# margin-left/right help needed

Tags: css, canvas

I'm having issues with centering a canvas horizontally. a display: table was added in order to center it vertically. very odd.

```
html, body {
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 85%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display:table;
}

#container2 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;   
}​

<div id="container">
    <div id="container2">
    <img src="http://cultureandcommunication.org/tdm/nmrs/fa1/files/2010/10/lolcats4.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>​
```

jsfiddle.net/tGtDv/1

Comment: Please extend this question with all neccessary data. As it stands this question is utterly useless for the archive.

Comment: I agree. There is literally no information here. "I have a problem here's a link, figure it out." Not a very good question at all.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forums ... Please read the FAQs

Comment: "Now I need help centering the canvas horizontally" + the fiddle is enough data for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block elements can be centered by setting the margin left and right to `auto`.

```css
div.container2 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

If you want to align center both horizontally as vertically, you need a different approach with a set width and height.

```css
div.container2 {
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    width: 200px;
}
```

In this case, you position an element 50% to the left and 50% to the right of it's parent element. Because HTML elements' origin is in the top left, you have to shift it a little. That's what the margins are for.

Comment: You can also use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align` for vertical centering.

Comment: @LeviBotelho interesting... that would allow elements to have a dynamic height - how well is it supported?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken basically IE8+. Firefox and Chrome have supported `display: table-cell` for quite a while.

Comment: how can I do it without a set width/height? doing so defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do as I'm trying to use this container dynamically to load pictures with different dimensions into a canvas. 

orig: http://jsfiddle.net/tGtDv/1/ 

yours: http://jsfiddle.net/tGtDv/2/ it's shifted, but not fully.

Comment: After some fiddling I have worked out a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/dnnPe/1/ Please note that the browser support is less than the other method I used with static sizes!